# how do you delete a metric in appdynamics?

Tags: appdynamics

With the Analyze -> Metric browser in AppDynamics, you can go in and look at all the various metrics in the tree, but there's no right-click "edit" option.  How do you modify/delete a metric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out if you go to configure -> instrumentation -> JMX tab then voila, you can now delete metrics and modify/edit them. But nowhere else. Odd.